# How do I equip the knife as a secondary weapon?

Tags: call-of-duty-black-ops-2

In CoD Black Ops 2, how can I equip the knife when I have both a primary and a secondary weapon? Is there a way? If not, does the tac knife for pistols count as an equipped knife?

I am asking this question in relation to the knife camo challenges, which require the knife to be equipped.

Thanks.

Comment: Is this to do with unlocking the skins for the knife? If so, I believe (not verified, hence why I've added as a comment) that the knife has to be 'equipped' in place of a secondary weapon. i.e. don't take a secondary so you can run around with your knife in your hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Knife comes as the default melee weapon and is neither a primary nor secondary. You don't need to equip it, and it takes no slot.

Tactical Knife is a secondary weapon *attachment*, like a supressor, and replaces your melee attack *while equipped*. If you switch to your primary, your melee attack will be your regular knife, which is slower.

**What you need, though**, is basically achieved by NOT equipping a secondary weapon.
Then you can run around with the knife, when you switched to secondary, and behold your camo.

Comment: I asked this question in relation to the knife camo challenges, which require the knife to be equipped.

Answer (score -1):

you can not unless you have no secondary

Comment: Hi James, and welcome to Arqade!  We often find that short, one line answers are not very helpful.  Please try to put more effort into your answers, such as fully explaining yourself or providing links to sources (as well as quoting relevant sections).  Users are less likely to upvote answers like this, and in fact are much more likely to downvote them instead.